# MasterPageFile reference path is incorrect on server, fine on localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, path, master-pages

I am trying to deploy my application to our webserver, but all of my paths are incorrect. I am getting an error that says file '/lsonet/RedSideMenu.master' does not exist. This is in the default.aspx page. On the default.aspx page, I have

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/RedSideMenu.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

on the server, it should be server/lsonet/BrokerBuy/Redsidemenu, so it is neglecting the base folder (BrokerBuy). On my local host, it uses http://localhost:4353/BrokerBuy/Default.aspx, which is correct. Is there a way that I can reference the server root path/BrokerBuy/page name in the master page reference? I don't want to have to change all of my links to account for the weird root folder (missing BrokerBuy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an application in the BrokerBuy directory on the web server. You do this in IIS.  At the moment, there is an application set in the isonet directory, so your pages think everything starts there.